# Is there an English phrase or word for someone who exhales quickly air (because of a funny thing for example) and then smiles?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I wanted to write a story where the female character says something silly to the male character, so he (the word I want to find) exhales quickly and then smiles at her.

Answer (score 2):

The closest word is probably *snort*, [to make an explosive sound by forcing air quickly up or down the nose](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/snort). However, this *only* describes the exhaling, not the smiling. Some languages may have a single word to express the two actions together, but that is not the case in English.

Note that two of the examples given by Cambridge are:

> Camille snorts when she laughs.

As well as:

> By this time I was snorting with laughter.

In general, I would say that people are more likely to exhale when snorting with laughter than to inhale, so this fits the first half of your action reasonably well.

Similarly, [this site](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/snort) seems to take it as given that it involves exhaling (though it need not, it at least indicates a tendency):

> make a snorting sound by exhaling hard.

However, note that "snorting" would rarely refer to exhaling with the mouth alone to express laughter.

If you want to refer to the exhalation and the smiling together, you would likely have to use two verbs: "He snorted with amusement and smiled." It is perhaps also worth keeping in mind here that the actions used to express amusement are not entirely universal across cultures, so if (for instance) this is a situation where the character is exhaling rapidly through their *mouth* and then smiling, this would not be common in some English-speaking countries, which might be why English would lack a single word for it.

Comment: People appear to inhale when they snort coke.

Answer (score 0):

**Gag, choke, gasp** are equally good.

**Puff** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/puff))

(countable) A sharp exhalation of a small amount of breath through the mouth.

(countable) A sudden but small gust of wind, smoke, etc.

Comment: None of these invoke the smile element.